# Select text functionality. Not working in webview using android3.1 tablet.

Tags: android, webview

Select text functionality is not working in android3.1 tablet  using phone gap. Can anybody tell what is wrong?. Here is my code.

```
 try{

            KeyEvent shiftPressEvent =    
               new KeyEvent(0, 0, KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN,    
               KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SHIFT_LEFT, 0, 0);
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "before shiftPressEvent.dispatch");
           shiftPressEvent.dispatch(super.appView);   
           Log.i(LOG_TAG, "after shiftPressEvent.dispatch");
          }catch(Exception e){   
           throw new AssertionError(e);   
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
KeyEvent shiftPressEvent = new KeyEvent(0,0,KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN,KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SHIFT_LEFT,0,0);
shiftPressEvent.dispatch(appView);
```